# Как указать относительный путь при копировании?

Tags: windows, cmd

Имеется:

1. файл file.txt в папке **D:\Test**
2. файл file.txt в папке **D:\x64_this-is-my-test_54321_99.88.77.555_folder_n12345**

Как используя командную строку

```
(FOR /R [[диск:]путь] %переменная IN (набор) DO команда [параметры])
```

Cкопировать (xcopy /o /y)

C заменой файл `file.txt` из папки `D:\Test` в папку `D:\x64_this-is-my-test_54321_99.88.77.555_folder_n12345`, если известно только что наименование второй папки начинается с `x64_this-is-my-test`, а дальнейший набор символов неизвестен?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Ответ не исчерпывающий, но подсказывающий как доделать самому.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я понял, что расположение второй папки известно, проблемы только с наименованием.
Если это так, попробуйте использовать короткие имена файлов. Должно получится что-то в стиле  x64thi~ или  x64_th~.

подробнее тут : https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/kb/142982/ru

Если короткие имена не подходят, можно попробовать несколько извращенный вариант.

```
for /d %%f in ("x64_this-is-my-test*") do echo %%f
```

в результате в переменную %%f будут последовательно подставлены каталоги, попадающие под маску "x64_this-is-my-test*"

Comment: Короткие имена не подойдут: Во-первых на некоторых компьютерах отключена генерация коротких имен. Во-вторых, хотя расположение известно и всегда постоянно, но количество папок начинающихся на x64_this-is может варьироваться на разных компьютерах. У кого-то есть папка: x64_this-is-Smit-test_54321_99.88.77.555_folder_n12345 А у кого-то еще есть папка: x64_this-is-my-beta_54321_99.88.77.555_folder_n12345 Известно что у всех есть папка начинающаяся x64_this-is-my-test, но текущий ее номер неизвестен. Вот и ищу команду которая бы дописала оставшийся путь.

Comment: А если так? `for /d %%f in ("x64_this-is-my-test*") do echo %%f`

Comment: Спасибо за направление. 
Мне надо было скопировать, а не вывести(найти) неизвестный путь.
Заменил на команду копирования + добавил путь к файлу и все сработало.

Comment: У меня не было возможности экспериментировать с копированием. Думал и так достаточно понятно. Что бы сказать спасибо есть специальные кнопочки, про то, что ответ подошел)